# Прозрачный прокси

Tags: прокси, proxy, ubuntu

Возникла необходимость ограничить клиентским машинам доступ к развлекательным сайтам. На машинах используется Ubuntu. Каким образом лучше проверить статистику посещения сайтов и запрета к некоторым сайтам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прокси не обязательно делать прозрачным, достаточно убрать NAT в Интернет на "дефолтном шлюзе", а дальше в гугле:

```
squid статистика посещения сайтов
```

и

```
squid blacklist
```

Comment: После того как "достаточно убрать NAT в Интернет на "дефолтном шлюзе"" в гугл то будет не попасть)))

Comment: для всей сети по DHCP, кроме себя лубимого, которому нужно прописать его ручками )))